# How Configure HTML for Incoming Data

Tags: html, css

I started a new project and my task is to write the HTML layout for data that will be coming in through some data loads (which will be text).  The text will be different based on some user clicks I'm not responsible for.  I know I will be using a unique id which it will search for. So I'm wondering do I just configure my HTML and CSS and don't worry about the data loads coming in or is there something I need to be aware of?

Thanking You In Advance

PDH

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create websites the content of which will be dependent on user actions then you might want to take a look at backend languages such as [PHP](https://secure.php.net/). An example site using PHP would look as follows:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["input"]))
    echo "You typed ".$_POST["input"];
?>
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="input">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, its not based on user input just on what is clicked, if a certain product is click a warning should show in either a popup or becomes un-hidden.    PDH

Comment: @user2280852 Then you're looking for JavaScript. JavaScript can be used within HTML's `<script>` tag to manipulate the DOM, e.g., show or hide an element.